# How do I pass a string to a program without formatting?

Tags: powershell

`gci something | select {$_.FullName} | foreach {.\echoargs.exe $_}` shows that what I thought was just a string gets passed to the executable as `@{$_.FullName=C:\something}`. If I try and "convert it even more to a string" with something like .ToString() it just gets added in as `@{$_.FullName.ToString()=` How can I get rid of this extra `@{` formatting and pass only the string to an executable?

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` or `(Get-ChildItem -Path something).FullName`

Comment: This worked, thank you. If you'd like to post the same thing as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have experienced is that PowerShell sends a 'stringified' representation of the object(s) you have, like `@{$_.FullName=C:\something}`.

`Get-ChildItem` (gci) returns FileInfo or DirectoryInfo **objects** with lots of properties.
Piping that to `Select-Object FullName` then returns **object(s)** with one property, namely the FullName, but nevertheless, they are still objects, not strings.

What you really want is to send just the fullname path as **string**, so you need to either use

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

or

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path something).FullName
```

to get (an array of) strings that will be sent to the external application.